# how to create multisite linkage of data in wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, multisite

how to create multisite linkage of data in wordpress multisite, where main site is www.example.com, second site is seller.example.com and the backend is for maintaining for the backend team. I want the data that occurs in the main site www.exmaple.com to www.seller.example.com and I want both the data to be connected to the backend team. This site must work like amazon or flipkart. How do i connect the database between the main site www.example.com, www.seller.example.com to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to do the multisite in the same Data base ? Normally when you active the Multisite and Install the network, and create a sub-domaine like seller.example.com you can have data in the same Data base

Comment: yes. It must be just like www.amazon.com is for customers and seller.amazon.com which is for sellers and they have a backend for amazon employees to access info of customers and the sellers. I want to do the same.